# How to change a PostgreSQL parameter requiring server restart, using postgres -c

Tags: postgresql, parameter

I need to temporarily change a parameter that requires server restart.
The command is as follows:

```
postgres -c checkpoint_segments=30 -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data"
```

Where `checkpoint_segments` is the parameter, and `-D` specifies the directory containing the `postgresql.conf` file.

However, I get the following message upon running the command:

```
2015-10-12 11:44:55 EDT     |LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: No error
2015-10-12 11:44:55 EDT     |HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2015-10-12 11:44:55 EDT     |LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: No error
2015-10-12 11:44:55 EDT     |HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2015-10-12 11:44:55 EDT     |WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "*"
2015-10-12 11:44:55 EDT     |FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

What is wrong with my command?

Note: Using PostgreSQL 9.2.2 for Windows 32 bits.

Comment: It looks like another PostgreSQL instance is already running

Comment: Craig, there was indeed another cluster running 9.3, and I shut it down. But strangely, the same error message occurs now when I run the above command.